# bdw-gc install failed on lion with brew

Tags: osx-lion, homebrew, w3m

i am install w3m with brew on lion. when i use the origin formula the installation is filed.
then i following the issues 7068 of homebrew update the bdw-gc.rb formula script

```
require 'formula'
class BdwGc < Formula
#  url 'http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gc_source/gc-7.1.tar.gz'
  url 'http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gc_source/gc-7.2alpha6.tar.gz'
  homepage 'http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/'
# 7.1
#  md5 '2ff9924c7249ef7f736ecfe6f08f3f9b'
#  7.2alpha6
  md5 '319d0b18cc4eb735c8038ece9df055e4'

  fails_with_llvm "LLVM gives an unsupported inline asm error", :build => 2335

  def install
    # ucontext has been deprecated in 10.6
    # use this flag to force the header to compile
#    ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-D_XOPEN_SOURCE" if MacOS.snow_leopard?
    ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-D_XOPEN_SOURCE"# if MacOS.snow_leopard?

    system "./configure", "--disable-debug", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

and reinstall it, but it's still failed. here is the install log

```
brew install bdw-gc 
==> Downloading http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gc_source/gc-7.2alp
File already downloaded in /Users/akira/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-gc/6
==> make install
```

........

```
libtool: compile:  /usr/bin/llvm-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./include -I./include -I./libatomic_ops/src -I./libatomic_ops/src -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -fexceptions -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe -c obj_map.c -o obj_map.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/llvm-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./include -I./include -I./libatomic_ops/src -I./libatomic_ops/src -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -fexceptions -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe -c -o pcr_interface.lo pcr_interface.c
./libatomic_ops/src/atomic_ops/sysdeps/gcc/x86_64.h: In function 'AO_test_and_set_full':
./libatomic_ops/src/ato==> Exit Status: 2
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/bdw-gc.rb#L22
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: bc90bd554da6bd1199bdec92a830edbca24fa34e
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.2
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 4.2
GCC-4.0: N/A 
GCC-4.2: build 5666 
LLVM: build 2336 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CXX: /usr/bin/llvm-g++ => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
LD: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe
CPPFLAGS: -D_XOPEN_SOURCE
MAKEFLAGS: -j4

Error: Failed executing: make install 
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7068
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
```

any suggestion?

Comment: how this question has anything to do with emacs.?

Comment: i want use w3m text browser from emacs. i need to install it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem was fixed by Jack Nagel at Nov 15, 2011.
see the detail

[bdw-gc: add 7.2alpha6 as the '--devel' version](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/56afd5152ac8f739057f70f743f62e3321c9c6f2/Library/Formula/bdw-gc.rb)

but this batch still got a problem. the "make check" step does not works,so you can just skip this step and "make install".